# "\escapechar" vs category 0 in TeX

Tags: tex-core, catcodes

In TeX, `` \catcode`\|=0 `` will make escape character to be `|`, to `|TeX` will output

[image: Figure 1]

But at the penultimate paragraph of page 40 of **The TeXbook**, it says that `\escapechar` is normally TeX's internal code for backslash. However, `` \escapechar=`\| `` could not make `|TeX` to output the result as `\TeX` does.

```
\escapechar=`\| 
%\catcode`\|=0
\TeX\par
|TeX
\bye
```

[image]

What is the difference between `\escapechar` and category 0 in TeX?

Comment: \escapechar=256 
 \TeX\par
 \string\TeX
\bye   and you will understand what it does. TEX does not need not use the backslash character to display a control sequence: it uses character number`|\escapechar`. It does not have any relation to catcodes. For a clever construction see how `\newif` is defined.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides  `\escapechar=256 \TeX\par \string\TeX \bye` outputs nothing. What did you get? This one `Tkern -.1667emlower .5exhbox {E}kern -.125emX`?

Comment: Yes if the escapechar is negative or more than 255 the escapechar is not output.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Why in my case `|TeX` produces `---TeX`?

Comment: with pdftex it should have shown |TeX  try put \tt before to see if it is a font or setup issue

Comment: @YiannisLazarides With `\tt` before, it produces `|TeX`, which I don't think is right as without ``\escapechar=`\| ``, it also produces `|TeX`.

Comment: the --- is nothing to do with escapechar it is just how | typesets in OT1 encoding. use \tt or in latex `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: Try `\escapechar=`\A  \string\TeX  should give you ATeX

Comment: @YiannisLazarides It is very difficult to understand. If in ``\escapechar=\A \string\TeX``, the `\ ` in `\TeX` is escape character, `A`, is `A` equals to `\ `?

Comment: `\TeX`. The `\escapechar` ONLY affects how `string` or `\write`  outputs the escape character!

Comment: @YiannisLazarides What is the meaning of changing the escape character output by `\string` or `\write`? And how did you know this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\escapechar` is relevant only when *representing* control sequences.

Remember, as I recently explained, that the category code 0 prefix is how TeX understands it has to form a control sequence token (as opposed to a character token), but then the only relevant aspect is the *name* of the control sequence.

In the TeXbook this is underlined by specifying the name inside a box when the discussion is about tokens.

However, sometimes TeX needs to represent a control sequence token: this happens when TeX is processing `\string`, `\write` or `\message`.

The `\string` primitive is expandable and its action is:

1. examine the following token;
2. if the token is a character, make it category code 12 or 10;
3. if the token is a control sequence, make the characters forming the control sequence's name category code 12 or 10 and prepend the character with character code `\escapechar` if the integer register stores a value between 0 and 255 (inclusive), otherwise nothing;
4. remove `\string` and the following token;
5. put back the characters so obtained in the input stream.

Category code 12 is assigned to all characters so formed, except that space characters get category code 10. The upper bound is `0x10FFFF` for Unicode engines.

During `\write` and `\message` the action is similar, just category codes are irrelevant: tokens are expanded, unexpandable token are written out like described for `\string`.

Note that the value of `\escapechar` is in no way related to what character has category code 0. By default the value of `\escapechar` is 92, that is, the ASCII code of the backslash, but any user can change it.

Thus the normal action when TeX finds `\string\TeX` is to put

`\`<sub>12</sub>`T`<sub>12</sub>`e`<sub>12</sub>`X`<sub>12</sub>

in the input stream. But if you do

```
{\escapechar=`| \string\TeX}
```

what you get in the input stream is

`|`<sub>12</sub>`T`<sub>12</sub>`e`<sub>12</sub>`X`<sub>12</sub>

If you don't change the value of `\escapechar` from the initial one, with

```
{\catcode`|=0 |string|TeX}
```

you still get

`\`<sub>12</sub>`T`<sub>12</sub>`e`<sub>12</sub>`X`<sub>12</sub>

because the character used for determining that a control sequence token is to be formed is in ***no way*** remembered by TeX.

Comment: So, are `\catcode` and `\escapcharr` independent, just they all locate in 92 by default？

Comment: @campa of course not!

Comment: @Y.zeng Quoting my answer: “Note that the value of `\escapechar` is in no way related to what character has category code 0.”